# Mail server with mailbox store in more than one machine

Tags: email, postfix

I have a mail server for a domain foo.com. Currently all users mail box is also in the same server. Now this company is starting its operation in multiple Countries. How can I have mailbox store of the users in one country to be stored locally in a server in that country office server. My current setup is a combination of Postfix + Courier IMAP + MySQL + Amavisd-new + SpamAssassin + ClamAV + SASL . Basically what I need is user A's mails should go to the server in Country A and user B's mails should go to the server in Country B. If my question is not clear enough I am open to questions. One main thing here is the domain name should be the same for all users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use transport maps. Transport maps gives you the flexibility to direct individual users/domains to different email servers.